# Flutter - Draggable text doesn't go to next line

Tags: flutter

I'd like to make draggable text go to next line if text is too long.
draggable text look like this

```
return Positioned(
    left: position.dx,
    top: position.dy,
    child: Draggable(
      data: widget.index,
      child: new GestureDetector(
            child: new Text(
              widget.caption.caption,
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: widget.caption.color,
                fontSize: widget.caption.fontSize,
              ),
              softWrap: true,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              widget.callback(widget.caption, widget.index);
            },
          ),
      onDragStarted: widget.setDragging,
      onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
        setState(() {
          position = offset;
          widget.secondCallback(offset, widget.index);
          widget.endDragging();
        });
      },
      feedback: new Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: new Text(
          widget.caption.caption,
          style: new TextStyle(
              color: widget.caption.color,
              fontSize: widget.caption.fontSize),
         softWrap: true,
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

But when I typed long text, still one line and can't see text that overflowed.
I wrapped text with column, flex, flexible, but not wrapping text.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap your `Text` like below,

```
new Row(children: <Widget>[
      new Flexible(
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              widget.caption.caption,
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: widget.caption.color,
                fontSize: widget.caption.fontSize,),
             softWrap: true,
          )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ])
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer but still not go to next line.